# PHP replace weird space

Tags: php, utf-8, whitespace

I have and Excel file that I converted to a CSV file. Apparently there are two kinds of `spaces` in this file, the regular space and a non-breaking space *(my assumption)*.

When saving the data to the database the non-breaking space gets saved as a black diamond with a question mark (�).

I've been reading around as this probably has solutions already but when I try them, nothing is happening.

Using the `mb_substr` approach:

```
$name = !empty($data[0]) ? mb_substr($data[0], 0, mb_strlen($data[0]), "UTF-8") : null;
```

Using the `str_replace` approach:

```
$name = !empty($data[0]) ? str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $data[0]) : null;
```

#### Edit

I'm using Oracle for the database and here are the Character Sets defined:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET       = AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
```

Here's a sample data:

, W.R.,

The space before W is the character that gets transformed into the question mark.

Comment: what kind of database are you using? Maybe the DB isn't configured to use UTF-8?

Comment: Have a look through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through it could be anything really.

Comment: when you say saving to the database, what database are you using?? MySQL??  what's your database character set?? is it UTF-8 unicode??

Comment: Can you link the Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with `iconv`:

```
$name = !empty($data[0]) ? iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $data[0]) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your settings for the Excel program and see if you can establish the character set of the original file you can then upload the file and use PHP [`MB_convert_encoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) function to translate from whatever Excel saves it as to `UTF-8`,  or better yet simply export it as UTF-8 directly from Excel.

also be aware that if you're using MySQL the `UTF8_` character set is [BROKEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and `UTF8mb4` should be used instead.